# how i can add a vue template in exist project

Tags: vue.js

how i can add a vue template like this :

[vue-paper-dashboard](https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-paper-dashboard/#/dashboard)

in my vue cli project

i want just add it in specify route like :

/admin/

in [documentaion](https://demos.creative-tim.com/vue-paper-dashboard/documentation/) just write about run demo

but its folder like a complete project and i dont know how i can add it to specify part of my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly what you can do to is right click on the vue-pager-dashboard and inspect so the developer tools shows up. When the developer tools shows up click on the sources like the picture below

[image]

After that you will see webpack you can go in there and see how they made their files and designed the dashboard so you can from there work your way and copy the important parts that you want in your project. In the (. dot) folder you can see the routes plugins etc.. and in the src folder you can see pages components well in both folders you can see the components. So this is the way you can do it but if it isn't as you asked or didn't help you out be more specific with your question.

[image]